# (struct name*)b->c what does it mean?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

Given the structure as following

```
typedef struct {
    char *a;
    char *val;
} kvp;
```

and

```
typedef struct node {
    void *val;
    node *next;
} node;

node *n;
kvp *p = (kvp *)n->val;
```

what is `p` when it's declared as `kvp *p = (kvp *)n->val;`

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Why is it violating strict aliasing? `val` is `void*`

Comment: It's a cast which might invoke undefined behaviour. What _exactly_ are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is valid only if `void *val` was of type `kvp *`, and ofc that `n` is valid.

Comment: @michael walz as per the title, i want to know whats the behavior happen to p. Can struct declared with parentheses?

Comment: You don't use casts that way and even less if you don't know what you're doing. Casts arfe explained in your C textbook.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is explained in the every C book.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about operator precedence, the `->` has higher precedence than the cast.

```
// This expression
(kvp *)n->val
// is evaluated as this:
(kvp *)(n->val)
// NOT this:
((kvp *)n)->val
```

[Source](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) (Google "C operator precedence")